# Does a normal iTunes backup instead of the iCloud one save the wifi passwords?

Tags: wifi, password, recovery

In case I restore my phone or change for a brand new.

Comment: Do you have your iTunes backup encrypted? I know that if it is, it can save things like Health data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wi-Fi passwords on iOS are stored in the keychain, which is only part of an **iTunes backup if encrypted backups are enabled**. If you enable encrypted backups, a future backup of the device using iTunes will contain the Wi-Fi network password. Passwords cannot be added retroactively to backups. Backups to iCloud will always contain the keychain containing the Wi-Fi network password.

> Encrypted iTunes backups can include information that unencrypted iTunes backups don't: Wi-Fi settings

[About encrypted backups in iTunes - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205220)

To enable encrypted backups, check the checkbox on the device page in iTunes.

> [image: iTunes device page showing Encrypt iPhone backup checkbox]

Comment: I have to say that this is a very useful response put in a very elegant way, congratulations, it is very satisfaying.